Конвертирование текста из мультилинейного текстбокса в текст определённого формата
Итак! У нас есть многострочный Textbox "CustomStropheTb".
В него забивается текст формата:
10А
11Б
10А
11Б

т.е. Между текстовыми атрибутами у нас идёт перенос строки.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в атрибут strophe выходил текст без переноса строк, в формате: "10Апробел11Бпробел10Апробел11Б".

А в чём проблема заменить перевод строки на пробела?

В том, что через Replace оно почему-то выводит с переносом строк.

Значит не все меняете. Поставьте точку остановки и посмотрите какая строка у вас в CustomStropheTb, какие там символы переноса.

А как можно менять не все? Ну, в плане, ты буквально string s = CustomStropheTb.Text;  s.Replace("\n", " "); А оно всё ещё выводит текст с переносом строки.

Еще раз повторю, поставьте точку остановки и посмотрите, что у вас в этой строке! Скорей всего у вас там 10\r\n11\r\n\12\r\n.... Научитесь пользоваться отладкой, это ведь самый важный инструмент программиста.

Используйте свойство Environment.NewLine - оно содержит необходимые символы в зависимости от ОС.

myString = myString.ReplaceLineEndings(" ");

@BorisD отличный метод, но .NET 9 ещё не вышел в релиз.

@aepot Этот метод начиная с .NET 6

@BorisD вы правы, я документацию неправильно прочитал.
